# What's the purpose of assigns method in Rails tests (MiniTest)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Used in automatically generated tests:

```
test "should create item" do
  login_user
  assert_difference('Item.count') do
    post :create, item: { creator: @item.creator, title: @item.title, user_id: @item.user_id, text: 'Hello, world!' }
  end

  assert_redirected_to(assigns(:item))
end
```

Rails [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/TestProcess.html#method-i-assigns) doesn't have any description. What's the purpose of this method and how to use it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It means if a controller defined an instance variable `@item="something"`.

You can fetch an instance variable in your test with e.g.:

```
# It will check if the instance variable is a string.
assert_kind_of String, assigns(:item)
```

Answer (score 6):

Be aware `assigns` deprecated in Rails 5. And extracted to separate gem.
To use it you must include 'rails-controller-testing' to your gemfile.

Comment: Wanted to clarify since I was curious, found the article, and it does seem that they want to deprecate the entire concept for assigns (and templates) as tests should not care about those internal decisions/mechanisms in such detail, so the gem is just as needed to transition to not requiring those instructions in a test suite in the future.  https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html  Thanks for the lead!