# Accessing controller instance variables with Minitest

Tags: ruby, tdd, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org, minitest

I'm trying to access the instance variables inside my controllers with minitest.

For example:

microposts_controller.rb:

```
def destroy
  p "*"*40
  p @cats = 42
end
```

How would I test the value of `@cats` with inside `microposts_controller_test.rb` with minitest?

I know I can submit the `delete` request from the browser and check my server logs and find:

```
"****************************************"
42
```

I read in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214443/whats-the-purpose-of-assigns-method-in-rails-tests-minitest) that I have access to an `assigns` hash with all the instance variables but it didn't work. I've also tried looking inside the `controller` object. Shown below:

microposts_controller.rb:

```
test "@cats should exist in destroy method" do 
  delete micropost_path(@micropost)
  p controller.instance_variables
  p assigns[:cats]
end
```

output:

```
[:@_action_has_layout, :@_routes, :@_request, :@_response, :@_lookup_context, :@_action_name, :@_response_body, :@marked_for_same_origin_verification, :@_config, :@_url_options]0:04
nil
```

I was expecting to see the `@cats` instance variable inside the `controller` object. I was also expecting to see `42` being output.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a `before_action` that checks to make sure the user is logged in, so the `delete` request was getting redirected.

I also have a test helper that will put a valid user id into the session. Using that everything works as expected :)

microposts_controller_test.rb:

```
test "@cats should exist?" do
  log_in_as(users(:michael))
  delete micropost_path(@micropost)
  p controller.instance_variables
  p assigns[:cats]
end
```

test_helper.rb:

```
def log_in_as(user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

output:

```
[:@_action_has_layout, :@_routes, :@_request, :@_response, :@_lookup_context, :@_action_name, :@_response_body, :@marked_for_same_origin_verification, :@_config, :@current_user, :@_params, :@micropost, :@cats, :@_url_options]
42
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `view_assigns`:

```
# asserts that the controller has set @cats to true
  assert_equal @controller.view_assigns['cats'], true
```